# How to access HashMap values in java script method?

Tags: java, javascript

Here is my java code

```
public HashMap<Integer, Integer> getNoOfWidgetsFromUsername(final String username) //vikas- method to get pid from db.
{
HashMap<Integer, Integer> obMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
int numwidgets=getTotalWidgetsOfUser(PartnerID);
obMap.put(new Integer(1),PartnerID);
obMap.put(new Integer(2),numwidgets);
return obMap;
}
```

I put the above code in a function. I am calling that function from Javascript and returning values to Javascript.

Here is my Javascript code.

```
JSClientService.getNoOfWidgetsFromUsername(username, {
callback : function(data) {
//here i want to print hashmap values.
}
});
```

How can I access the data on the Javascript side?

Comment: How is the java object getting to the JS code?

Comment: I assume you're returning JSON, your question is vague

Comment: what technology are you using in your frontend? A java servlet?

Comment: what is `JSCLientService` ? Which library you are using for that. Please add tag.

Comment: Rakesh: JSclientService is used to call java script method,

Comment: @Vicky That is fine. But there is nothing like JSCLientService in javascript. I guess you are using some library, hopefully DWR ? If yes then add DWR tag, or else please tell us which library is tht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Java object, so you can not access it in javascript (i guess *data* will be undefined in your case).

Convert your java object to JSON object (something like this)

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("res",obmap);
```

then in your js callback function ()

```
callback : function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i in data.res){
      console.log(i); //key
      console.log(data.res[i]); //value  
  }
}
```

*code not tested*