# How to get json values in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I am having a servlet in which I am getting the value of properties file and putting that value in HashMap. How do I get all these map values in ajax jquery and set each map value to each textbox.I want to get links, appdb and appws in ajax and set it to textboxes -#links,#appsb,#appws.

**SERVLET**

```
               JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
              Map<String,String> obj = new HashMap<String,String>();
                if (lookfor != null) {
                    for (String look : lookfor) {
                        //System.out.println("looking for :"+look);
                        String value =  prop.getProperty(app+"_"+look);
                        if(app.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                        if(look.equalsIgnoreCase("Links")){
                            String links=(String) prop.getProperty(app+"_"+look,"Links");
                            //System.out.println("Links of"+" "+name + "is"+" " +links);
                            json.put("appLink", links);
                        }
                        if(look.equalsIgnoreCase("DataBase")){
                            String appdb=(String) prop.getProperty(app+"_"+look,"DataBase");
                            //System.out.println("DB of"+" "+name+"is"+" "+appdb);
                            json.put("appDB", appdb);
                        }
                        if(look.equalsIgnoreCase("WebServices")){
                            String appws=(String) prop.getProperty(app+"_"+look,"WebServices");
                            //System.out.println("WebService of"+" "+name+ "is"+" " +appws);
                            json.put("appWebService", appws);
                        }
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to transfer the value to the javascript or to the servlet? if you want to post from the servlet to the javascript you might want to look at a library like https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ if you don't have it yet.

Comment: IMHO you should not return HashMap as it is from servlet, you need to format the output as a array or json. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327355/how-to-access-hashmap-values-in-java-script-method) similar question.

Comment: @learningloop  ok if I am sending it as json , how can I get it in ajax and set that value to three different textboxes

Comment: @AnushaSajeendran Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/learningloop/6a36w1pc/2/) jsfiddle.

Comment: @learnerloop In that demo the values are given manually..I want to get values from my servlet in ajax

Answer (score 0):

Following is the  way to return JSON Object from Java Servlet:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
// Get the printwriter object from response
// to write the required json object to the output stream      
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
// Assuming your json object is **jsonObject**, 
// perform the following, it will return your json object  
out.print(jsonObject);
out.flush();
```

Following is the way to get JSON object using AJAX:

```
$.getJSON('PropertyValueGetter?lookfor=Links', null,
        function(data){
            $("#links").val(data.appLink);
}); 

$.getJSON('PropertyValueGetter?lookfor=Database', null,
        function(data){
            $("#appdb").val(data.appDB);
}); 

$.getJSON('PropertyValueGetter?lookfor=WebServices', null,
        function(data){
            $("#appws").val(data.appWebService);
});
```